# How to iterate "Task<List<Object>>" in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am working with `C#` after a long time and I am trying to understand how to iterate `Task<List<User>>` object.

```
var productsTask = Execute(clientIds.ToList(), lc, this._getFaultPolicy,
                   (ct, batch) => mapper.FetchAsync<User>(selectStatement, batch), "GetAsyncCall");
```

Here `productsTask` is of type - `Task<List<User>> productsTask`. I tried looking around but couldn't figure out how to iterate this and print each User object? I was thinking to do like this but it gives an error which is obvious I guess:

```
foreach (var s in productsTask)
{

}
```

Comment: Well, you may get its `Result` or call `await`

Comment: `Task<T>` isn't enumerable, the result of the task is, in this case.

Comment: That is what I am also confuse how async and await works in c#? Await basically make sure that you get the result back right? Without await what does it mean?

Comment: @dragons That's way too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I updated my comment. Sorry typed too early

Comment: Sounds like you just need a good understanding of asynchronous programming. Microsoft has very well written articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). Start there. (that's just the first article in the series - the rest are in the table of contents on the left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having async/await in play. As @Gabriel Luci suggested, please do read about async/await programming (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), because this is crucial for you to continue working with the code and understanding "what is going on"

But anwser to your question simply is:

```
var products = await Execute(
                      clientIds.ToList(),
                      lc,
                      this._getFaultPolicy,
                      (ct, batch) => mapper.FetchAsync<User>(selectStatement, batch),
                      "GetAsyncCall"
                   )
                   .ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach(var product in products)
{
    //Do what you need here
}
```

The `.ConfigureAwait` fragment is especially important if you are constructing, for example, WinForms app. For Console app it doesn't matter. This is connected with the term of "SynchronizationContext"
You can read about this topic more here:

https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f

and

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/

It is not mandatory, but for sure "nice to have" till the moment, you are completely sure, you don't need it :)

Comment: That article you linked to specifically says "in your library code". Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in an app with a synchronization context (WinForms or ASP.NET) can have unintended consequences. It makes it possible to end up on a different thread after the `await`. In a WinFroms app, that means you won't be able to modify the UI. In ASP.NET, that means your `HttpContext` won't be available. People seem to recommend sprinkling their code with `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere, but it's a bad idea unless you know exactly what it does.

Comment: Yeah and here is more detailed article from MS: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/ I will update article with is as well. Libraries are "must have" to implement it. But normal code is "nice to have" as well. Look on SOF about issues with deadlocks compare to issues with empty HttpContext - and you will know, that it is choosin lower evil. Of course, knowing what you doing is the best option. But i suppose, @dragons is on the begining of his road, and "knowing what he is doing" will still come.

Comment: Deadlocks are the result of waiting synchronously on asynchronous code. The solution is not to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` - the solution is not not wait synchronously on asynchronous code because that defeats the whole purpose of using *any* asynchronous code. Stephen Toub says in that article you linked to (under the "When should I use ConfigureAwait(false)?" heading): "When writing applications, you generally want the default behavior (which is why it is the default behavior)."

Comment: @GabrielLuci - what you just said means exactly "understanding what you do" Person, who asked the question: "Why async operation return task" (it was not exactly the question but i hope you get the point) is very far from this "understanding" Microsoft even advise this as "best practise" See for yourself --> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming. Of course there is exception (as you stated) with methods that require context. I did assume, it was not the case here. The best is just to read and take decision.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - One minor clarification about your statement: `"In a WinFroms app, that means you  won't be able to modify the UI. In ASP.NET"` That is not true. It is more tricky, but it is doable. You just use Invoke on the control that you want to modify on UI. With proper helper it is even as easy as calling `"someLabel.SafeInvoke(t => t.Visible = false);` Of course, i don't imply - you should do it. I totally agree with you. The best is just to keep "async all the way" and to not to force synchronous waiting for async operations;)

Comment: Right, but you have to be aware that you might not be on the UI thread. My point is simply that people (especially ones new to asynchronous programming) should not be told to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere. The advise should be the opposite: never use it unless you know exactly what it does and have determined that you will benefit from it.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - your advice is totally contradictory to MS advice :) But I get your point. I assume, that MS give "best practices" in the way he did - simply because of issues created by both approaches (that you can create if you don't understand what you are doing:) ) Ok, i think it is enough for ConfigureAwait discussion :) EOT;)

Comment: My advice is not contradictory to Microsoft's advice. Their advice is to always use it *in libraries* (DLLs that you plan to give to other people to use in their applications). That is a specific case where you know what it does and know what the benefits are. Outside of libraries, "you generally want the default behavior (which is why it is the default behavior)".

Comment: @GabrielLuci - I am not referring to the article about the libraries (given in the post) i am referring to "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming" from MS. There is no information "in libraries" Read carefully ;) It is simply stated as "best practice" (you can of course disagree :) ) Somehow i am too. But for async/await rookie - i will advice it almost all the time.

Comment: Even there, it says "Use ConfigureAwait(false) *when you can*" and the exception is "Methods that require con­text". Inexperienced programmers don't know "when they can" or even what "context" means. That's the problem with telling them that it's "especially important if you are constructing, for example, WinForms app". It sets them up for strange exceptions down the road that they don't understand. If you want, point people to that article and tell them "Once you understand what `ConfigureAwait(false)` does, you can start introducing it in your code as a very small performance improvement."

Answer (score 0):

The [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) is an operator. You can use this operator anywhere you have an asynchronous operation (typically a `Task`) and you want its result.

```
foreach (var s in await productsTask)
{

}
```

Of course in order to be allowed to use the `await` operator, you need to be inside a method marked with the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) modifier.